Marriage In Jannah
Assalmualikum.I and one boy love each other but we are not in relationship. We cannot marry each other in this dunya because of some conditions. He married another woman in this dunya.But I am still single and died as a single person. Can we make Nikkah in Jannah if we both get into Jannah inshallah?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. As you are hopefully the one writing this post, you certainly are alive and have not died yet. To learn more about our site and the StackExchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Also check the site for related posts at least in the last couple of weeks we've got 2 or 3 similar questions that could already have an answer.

The answer is yes if you will not marry in this dunya because you are a woman but in case if you get married then you will be with your husband in Jannah, but the condition is different for men as men can have more than one wife simultaneously so he can marry you there no problem. Rest Allah knows best.
